# Styles elements generated via createElement

Tags: javascript, css

Issue is: after hitting the button on the HTML page, the html `<h5>` tag text changes on the page but the `<h5>` tag text color wont change to blue (expected behavior as CSS style doesn't reload after clicking the button).
What could be a possible workaround for solving this issue?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".test");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  a1 = document.createElement('h5');
  a1.className = "first";
  a1.textContent = 'Blue updated.';
  document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = a1.innerText;
  //newtext = document.createTextNode('abc');
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: blue;
}

.first {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h5 id="position">Text Color to be replaced to blue after hitting Blue button(but not happening)</h5>
<button class="test">Change to blue</button>
```

Above, after the button is clicked and the action listener is triggered, the HTML `<h5>` tag elements code are created with `a1 = document.createElement('h5'); a1.className = "first"`
The new text is displayed but the **color didn't change** (to blue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting only the textContent instead of [appending](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) the entire new H5 element

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".test");
const pos = document.querySelector('#position');

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const h5 = document.createElement('h5');
  h5.className = "first";
  h5.textContent = 'Blue updated.';
  
  pos.innerHTML = "";  // Empty
  pos.append(h5);      // Append!
});
```

```css
.test, .first { color: blue; }
```

```html
<h5 id="position">Text Color to be replaced to blue after hitting Blue button(but not happening)</h5>
<button class="test">Change to blue</button>
```

PS: You can also create some nifty reusable functions to handle the DOM querying and creation of elements, using a friendly syntax:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


// Example:

const elPos = el('#position');

el(".test").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const elH5 = elNew('H5', {
    textContent: "Blue updated",
    className: "first",
  });
  elPos.innerHTML = "";  // Empty
  elPos.append(elH5);    // Append!
});
```

```css
.test, .first { color: blue; }
```

```html
<h5 id="position">Text Color to be replaced to blue after hitting Blue button(but not happening)</h5>
<button class="test">Change to blue</button>
```

Comment: for the aboce code line, const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
I read [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) but unabe to find the syntax, can you provide me the docs where I can find the syntax or usage of the code line const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);I am unable to understand the para keyword used in the arrow function

Comment: @Richard `el` is just a shorthand utility function for both Document.querySelector ***and*** [Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector). The  `par` argument is used to change `document` into any other **parent** element like: `el("#child", myParentElement)` which is the same as writing:  `myParentElement.querySelector("#child")` - it's used when you want to limit your DOM query to a specific parent children, instead of the entire document. Read also: Element.querySelector(). Feel free to ask if you need clarification.

Comment: I want to see the value of sel and par in the arrow function to better understand so I debugged via console.log to see the value of par by changing the arrow function as :const el = (sel, par) => {console.log("sel is +" + sel);console.log("par value is " + par)};
el('#position');and then vale of sel is #position which is OK but value of par shows as undefined...so why is the par element showing value of undefined..thanks

Comment: @Richard because if you use that second argument (pass an Element) then it will not be undefined. As I pointed already out, *par* can be an Element or can be left *undefined*. If you pass an Element as that second argument - that Element will be used instead of `document`. See in the code: `(par || document)` - if `par` is undefined the `||` will fallback to `document.querySelector` (instead of using `par.querySelector`)

Comment: To repeat in short: *"If `par` is `undefined` use `document.querySelector()` otherwise use `par.querySelector()`"* - that simple.

Comment: @Richard you might want to use `par` for example when targeting the first `".container"` not in the entire document, but the one inside #footer: `const elFooter = el("#footer"); const footerContainer = el(".container", elFooter);` — The first time `document.querySelector("#footer")` was used, whilst the second time `elFooter.querySelector(".container")` was used - all with one simple `el()` function utility helper.

Comment: The syntax for that `el` function would be: `el(stringSelector, optionalElementParent)` - The `optionalElementParent` (since it's optional) fallbacks to `document`. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: I am getting the <par> value in below program but I was not able to use in action listeners, so please can you modify or attach a fresh HTML JS Snippet to see usage of <par> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="xcontainer">
<h5 id="position">Hello world</h5>
<button class="test">Change to blue</button>
</div>
<script>
const el = (sel, par) => {console.log(par);(par || document).querySelector(sel);}
const myElement = el('#position', xcontainer);

  </script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: @Richard as I said earlier, `par` accepts an Object Element, not a string or an undefined value. Currently `xcontainer` is undefined. You need to do first: `const xcontainer = el("#xcontainer");` and than your line `const myElement = el('#position', xcontainer);` will work as expected.

Comment: But, it makes no sense to use the second `par` attribute in your case, since you already go for ID elements. ID is considered to be unique! Therefore all you need is: `const myElement = el('#position');` without the parent reference.

Comment: @Richard if you find the usage of the `el()` function confusing and difficult, please don't use it. Use `document.querySelector()` as you would usually. `const myElement = document.querySelector('#position');` or `someParentElement.querySelectorAll(".child")`

Comment: @Richard if you still cannot solve a problem it's most likely that you have not presented your problem in its entirety. Might be you want to improve your question, add more markup, improve your test case.

Comment: @roko-c-buljan The utility function you provided is definitely useful..I just wanted to see (as commented in below code)  ```h5=document.createElement('h5');
h5.textContent= "hello 123";
h5.className= "parrot";
p6=document.createElement('p');
p6.textContent= "456 world";
p6.className= "para";
h5.append(p6);
document.body.appendChild(h5);
const e31=(x1,x2) => {x1.querySelector(x2);}//This code piece:x1.querySelector(x2);
e31(h5,'.para');```

Comment: @Richard I cannot understand what and why you have that function `e31` and what's supposed to actually do, sorry. I overall don't understand your follow-up question. Also  don't pollute the global scope by using uninitialized variables like `p5=`, `p6=` etc. Always use `const` or `let`. Find some good tutorial about the basics of the JavaScript language: [Introduction to JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)

Comment: In your above code, you're missing the understanding in the difference between Regular functions and - Arrow functions and their implicit return functionality. Find the difference about the two in the MDN Docs. It should be like: `const e31=(x1,x2) => { return x1.querySelector(x2);}` or **implicit return** like `const e31=(x1,x2) => x1.querySelector(x2);`

Comment: - Please do yourself a favor and don't name your functions like `e31` - such means nothing to anyone. Use instead the examples I provided - if you really want to stick to my examples, but since I see you're really struggling, I suggest you to simply use querySelector and querySelectorAll without any helpers wrappers - until you understand really well how they actually work.

Comment: `h5=document.createElement('h5'); h5.textContent= "hello 123"; h5.className= "parrot";` would then be i.e: `const h5 = elNew("H5", {textContent: "hello 123", className: "parrot"})` Please, take more time to explore the code and fully understand it.